# To define the length, is it insufficient that it is regular?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, curves

According to my book, a curve (continuous mapping) is called regular if it's differentiable and the derivative is never zero.

And generally, the length of a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^2$ is defined by $$L=\int_a^b \|\gamma'(t)\| dt.$$

Thus, in order to define the length, $\|\gamma'(\cdot)\|$ has to be integrable on $[a,b]$.

If $\gamma$ is regular, isn't the length of $\gamma$ necessarily defined ?

I think that even if $\gamma$ is regular, $\|\gamma'(\cdot)\|$ is not necessarily integrable ...

Comment: Usually the length of a curve is defined as the supremum of the length of all its inscribed polygonal paths.  In case the path is $C^1$ its length is the above integral.  Rectifiability has nothing to do with regularity.

Comment: O.K. Thank you for the comment. @MichaelHoppe